# Calculating Personality Diversity in The Sims

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let’s say we’re playing The Sims. We must pick five traits from a list of 10 unique traits (traits A – J), and these 5 traits make up the sim’s personality. How can we calculate a number that represents the level of diversity among multiple sims? Ideally, this number would range from 0 – 1, with 0 representing no diversity, and 1 representing high diversity.

To be clear, let’s imagine the following scenarios and what the resulting diversity index would be.

**Scenario One:**

- Sim 1 has traits A, B, C, D, E
- Sim 2 has traits A, B, C, D, E

Diversity Index = 0

**Scenario Two:**

- Sim 1 has traits A, B, C, D, E
- Sim 2 has traits F, G, H, I, J

Diversity Index = 1

**Scenario Three:**

- Sim 1 has traits A, B, C, D, E
- Sim 2 has traits A, B, C, D, E
- Sim 3 has traits F, G, H, I, J
- Sim 4 has traits F, G, H, I, J

Diversity Index = .5 (?)

How could we go about calculating a diversity index with the above information?

Comment: The way this is written sounds like homework.  If so, please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Are traits just the same or different, or are there degrees of difference? I.e., is A closer to B than to E?

Comment: You could easily define a distance between Sims (between 0 and 1) and then calculate the average distance in the set of Sims. In your example, it would give a diversity of 2/3 (each Sim is at a distance 0 of one other Sim, and at a distance of 1 of the two other Sims).

Comment: @Amy It's not, but I'll take that as a compliment I suppose :P

Comment: @Dave Each trait assigns different behavior to the sim. So there's not really a concept of A being closer to B; they all operate independently from each other. I just used letters for shorthand, but imagine these being things like "Lazy", "Active", "Loves Sports" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily define a distance between Sims (between 0 and 1) and then calculate the average distance in the set of Sims.

In your example, it would give a diversity of 2/3 (each Sim is at a distance 0 of one other Sim, and at a distance of 1 of the two other Sims).

Concerning the distance between two Sims: calculate the number of different traits, and divide by the number of traits affected to each Sim.

Concerning the diversity of a set `{S1, S2, ..., Sn}`, just calculate

```
diversity = 2/n(n-1) sum{i = 1 to n} sum{j = i+1 to n} distance (Si, Sj)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply! I apologize if this comes off as stupid, but I struggle a bit with math.
When you say "calculate the number of different traits, and divide by the number of traits affected to each Sim", could you clarify this more? In my example, I believe there are 10 different traits... but what's the criteria for determining if they're affected?

Comment: I'm imagining something like this:
1. For each sim, calculate the distance of their traits to every other active sim. (So if there are four sims, each sim gets compared against 3 other sims)
2. Once each sim has a distance, take the average of that for the final diversity index.

I'm just a little fuzzy on the distance calculation. Thanks!

Comment: For example, if two Sims has 2 elements in common, and 3 different elements, then their distance is equal to 3/5, as each Sim own 5 traits in total. Two "equal" Sims will be at distance 0. Two totally different Sims will be at distance 1. I assume that the number of traits of each Sim is a constant, 5 here.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now! I've got this implemented in my project and it's working great. Thanks so much for the help!!

Comment: You welcome. Fine that it fulfills your needs.